# program to find All numbers y , less than a number x having the bits set at places only where they are set in x.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, arithmetic, binary-operations, programming

consider for example **118** its binary representation is **1110110**.
I want to have all numbers that have bits set at places only at places where it is set in **118** as follows:

- **114**->**1110010**
- **112**->**1110000**
- **102**->**1100110**
- **98**->**1100010**
  and so on upto
- **20**->**0010100**
- **6**->**0000110**.
- **2**->**0000010**
- **0**->**0000000**

I want to write an efficient c++ program for the list of numbers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [StackOverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) ?

Comment: You're saying you want the $2^n$ combinations of digits where the only one-bits in the numbers align with where there are $n$ one-bits in your chosen number...  How about making an array with the bits of your chosen number and "count" your way up through it by flipping each of the one-bits bits in the usual order?  You could either have the full expanded number in the array or else have the one positions in a condensed version of it...  With the condensed version you can iterate through $2^n$ and just set the positions from the array and your iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Why not $2$?  Why not $0$?  Count the bits turned on in your starting number, $5$ in $118$.  Count from $0$ to $2^5-1$ in binary and use that to indicate which bits should be on.  If you count downward they will come out in downward order like you indicate.  If you don't want to include $0$, stop counting at $1$.

Comment: yes 2 and 0 are also there I forgot to mention it in there .

Comment: I didn't get what u said. can you please elaborate with smaller examples like 50.@RossMillikan.

Comment: Look at the binaries of the numbers you got from $118$.  You successively turned off some bits.  Write the numbers $30$ downwards (not $31$ because you didn't write $118$)underneath them, lining up the bits in the five columns that have $1$s in $118$.  You should see what I mean.